# Can not access to global variable declared inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Declared global variable inside func_a() but could not access to it from another function func_b()
I am a new in python, sorry if it seems to be odd question

I am using IDLE, when I wrote functions IDLE did not show error but when I call to this function it showed error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#110>", line 1, in <module>
    func_b()
  File "<pyshell#109>", line 3, in func_b
    return a + c
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

>>> def func_a():
    global a
    a = 2
    b = 3
    return a + b

>>> def func_b():
    c = 4
    return a + c

>>> func_b()
```

Comment: you need to specify that a is a global variable inside your func_b

Comment: you have to global it inside of func_b (and anywhere else).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Comment: @NicoT & David: Wrong. You only need to use `global` if you want to ***assign*** to a global variable.

Comment: you need to run the function `func_a()` in order to assign a value to `a`

Answer (score 3):

You never ran function `func_a`, so the global variable a was never instantiated and assigned. As soon as you run `func_a`, the variable will be assigned and you can run `func_b` subsequently.